# How to generate auto increment id from mongodb using yii2

Tags: mongodb, yii2

I am new in mongodb and yii2, I just want to know How can i add auto incremented id in mongodb using yii2. We already have _id in mongodb that generates unique id, But i want to generate my own auto increment id.

Comment: This question has been asked a few times, here is a doc link to the procedure to setup such a thing http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

Comment: Thanks but how i will integrate this in YII2

Comment: You can make it integrate into beforeSave to check if the _id is set and if not then source a incrementing ID from the process in the link

Comment: Can you please share any url with me, Where i can check code